# Without me, you must be a woman. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I have 2 arms, and 1 leg.
>   Without me, you must be a woman.
>   Man with 2 flags calls me U.
>   With an equal mark, every Japanese loves me.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are ...

> The letter **Y**.

I have 2 arms, and 1 leg.

> Describes the letter.

Without me, you must be a woman.

> Chromosomes - XY is male, XX (without a Y) is female

Man with 2 flags call me U.

> [image]
>  A man making a "Y" with their body and two flags is giving the semaphore signal for **U**.
>  (Thanks @Eric Tressler in TSL for the brain jog.)

With an equal mark, every Japanese love me.

> The letter Y with an equal sign superimposed on it is **¥**, the symbol used for Japanese yen (which of course people would love).